# How to render asciidoc with latexmath macros?

Tags: pdf

I am trying to compile asciidoc files that contain equations in the following format:

```
latexmath:[\(\mathbb{F}_p\)]

[latexmath]
++++
\begin{equation}
{K = k * G}
\end{equation}
++++
```

First I tried to use conventional tools like asciidoc chrome extension, but they do not recognize this syntax.
After a bit of googling I found out that I need to compile the file first to docbook xml format and then process it with dblatex to create Pdf or some other readable format.

But unfortunately this doesn't seem to work on my Ubuntu 14.04, I see a lot of errors when dblatex processes docbook files:

```
Error: no ID for constraint linkend: signature.
XRef to nonexistent id: signature
Error: no ID for constraint linkend: ch03_bitcoin_client.
XRef to nonexistent id: ch03_bitcoin_client

...

ch04.docbook.tex:188: Bad math environment delimiter.
ch04.docbook.tex:188: leading text: $\begin{equation}
ch04.docbook.tex:188: Undefined control sequence \+.
ch04.docbook.tex:188: leading text: $\begin{equation} {y^2 = (x^3 \+

...
```

What am I doing wrong?
In particular I'm interested in this file: https://github.com/aantonop/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc

Comment: Since this is very LaTeX spscific, you might have more success asking this question on [tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). Beware though that cross posting is not allowed on all [se] sites. So remove the question here.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of an old question, but I just figured this out myself, so just in case you don't have the answer, here goes...

For the inline equation, I was able to compile using

```
latexmath:[$\(\mathbb{F}_p\)$]
```

The second one, you don't need to use `\begin{equation}`.  AsciiDoc takes care of that for you.  Instead just do

```
[latexmath]
+++++++++++++
\{K = k * G\}
+++++++++++++
```

That's if you actually want the curly braces.  See [here](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/latexmath.pdf) for more details.

Also, if you want to use the equation environment to have your equation numbered, you can use `[latex]` instead of `[latexmath]`.

```
[latex]
----------------------------------
\begin{equation}
.
.
.
\end{equation}
----------------------------------
```